# How to fix self is not defined when firebase messaging method called in react ssr app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-ssr, razzle

I am trying to use firebase massaging in my SSR app which is created using https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle with-react-router-3. I am already using firebase which works great including hosting. But started throwing an error when I started adding messaging in the app.

My entry point looks like,

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/messaging';

import FirebaseConfig from 'config/firebase-config.json';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
}
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I am getting the bellow error when I start the server with `razzle start`

```
/Users/subkundu/Desktop/Work/Projects/React/ownerstown/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/index.ts:75
  if (self && 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope' in self) {
  ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

How do I fix it? Any lead will be amazing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you have to provide a check to see if the `window` is available.

```
let Messaging;
if (YOUR_CHECK_HERE) {
    Messaging = firebase.messaging();
}
// Then you can use "Messaging"
```

I'm not familiar with razzle. Accessing the `window` varies depending on Server Side Rendering (SSR) frameworks. I got the idea from this [post](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/30#issuecomment-264348589). When I ran into this problem with nuxt.js I was able to check for the `window` with this `process.browser`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for replying back. I fixed it a week back by doing something like
export default function isBrowser(func) {
  return process.browser ? func : () => isBrowser(func);
}

and using it in my file